# Problema NavigationDrawer+Tabbed Activity API19 (No se ve, en API >21 si)

Tags: android, menú, activity, navigationview, kitkat

tengo una aplicación que mezcla un NavigationDrawer con un TabbedActivity y he reducido el SDK mínimo de mi aplicación a la API19 y tengo el problema de que en esa API no aparece nada de la barra, ni el botón de menú ni el título ni los iconos. Para las APIs >21 no tengo ningún problema.

**(SOLUCIONADO en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864791/drawer-activity-on-api-level-19)**

Gracias!

Comment: Hola @Gonzalo Que tienes dentro de `res\values\styles.xml` y `res\values-v21\styles.xml` agregalos ahí debe ser el problema

Comment: y en el  `activity_main.xml`  que tienes? ó donde tienes el `DrawerLayout`? Además tienes también el `AppBarLayout` en el `content_main`, siendo que ya lo tienes en el `app_bar_main.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Lo he conseguido solucionar a través de otro post en stackoverflow.com pero ahora tengo el problema de que el layout es como mas grande que la pantalla por la parte de abajo ya que en pantallas donde tenia contenido y margen, se pierde el margen e incluso parte del contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de activity_main (donde está ya todo el layout)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/contenedor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="#981e73be"
        app:itemTextColor="#2E2E2E"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Styles I have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconTint="#981e73be"
    app:itemTextColor="#2E2E2E"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Yo he seguido estos dos tutoriales:
1.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPwFK3QQYzk
2.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aLFCpaoOZo